# how to count empty lines in python file

Tags: python

I would like to print the total empty lines using python. I have been trying to print using:

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
for line in f:
    if (line.split()) == 0:
```

but not able to get proper output

---

I have been trying to print it.. it does print the value as 0.. not sure what wrong with code..

print "\nblank lines are",(sum(line.isspace() for line in fname))

it printing as:
blank lines are 0
There are 7 lines in the file.
There are 46 characters in the file.
There are 8 words in the file.

Answer (score 6):

Since the empty string is a *falsy* value, you may use [`.strip()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm):

```
for line in f:
    if not line.strip():
        ....
```

The above ignores lines with only whitespaces.

If you want *completely empty* lines you may want to use this instead:

```
if line in ['\r\n', '\n']:
    ...
```

Comment: That was awfully quick x_x

Comment: ^ I witnessed the quickness

Answer (score 6):

Please use a context manager (`with` statement) to open files:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(sum(line.isspace() for line in f))
```

[`line.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) returns `True` (== *1*) if `line` doesn't have any non-whitespace characters, and `False` (== *0*) otherwise. Therefore, `sum(line.isspace() for line in f)` returns the number of lines that are considered empty.

---

[`line.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) always returns a list. Both

```
if line.split() == []:
```

and

```
if not line.split():
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE_NAME = 'file.txt'

empty_line_count = 0 

with open(FILE_NAME,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
      # The split method will split the word into list. if the line is
      # empty the split will return an empty list. ' == [] ' this will
      # check the list is empty or not.
       if line.split() == []:
            empty_line_count += 1

print('Empty Line Count : ' , empty_line_count)
```